# iOS 10 beta, Game Center, invite friend doesn't work

Tags: ios, game-center, ios10

I can't invite friends from my application by Game Center iOS 10 beta 1.

I try to use GKMatchMakerViewController on iOS 10 and my app sends invite link to friend by iMessage.

Friend gets message link like this :
https://www.icloud.com/share/0pVZ0ltWfeGmc806iDQMQ8w8A ,
but the link doesn't work.

Friend opens the link and gets page from iCloud beta with the text "Software update required
To accept game invitations, you will need iOS 10 or Mac OS X 10.12 or later.".

The same error when friend opens the link on iOS 9 or iOS 10 beta 1.

I saw presentation "611_whats_new_in_game_center" from WWDC16 and
saw that Messages-Based Invites works well.

my code to send invite is very simple:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];

GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
mmvc.turnBasedMatchmakerDelegate = self;

[window.rootViewController presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Is it my error? Could you give me a tip or example of code for inviting friends on Game Center in iOS 10?

Comment: I am also having issues with the new TurnBasedMatchMaker invites. Have you made any progress since your post?

Comment: I have not found any solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved by iOS 10 beta 6.

Comment: can you provide a link to the issue tracker that show the resolution, please ?